# How can a python application send a message to a telegram bot on behalf of my user profile?

Tags: python, telegram

I need to create a client-server application in python, but I do not have a white IP. I came up with a way to get around this limitation: telegram bot mediation (requires only one client to be connected at the same time, so it's ok).

But I have a problem: I can exchange messages with the client using the bot as a kind of server, but it is inconvenient due to the fact that only a text interface is available.

So I need the server to be able to send messages to the bot **as if I were doing it**. In other words, the server sends a message to the bot, the message is recorded as "sender my_username", then the client receives the messages, sends a response, then the server accepts the response. How to do this using the telegram api via http, without third-party libraries?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)